# Why isn't the padding attribute applied to my button

Tags: javascript, html, css

FYI, I'm trying to style my html document from my javascript file. Currently trying to style my buttons using a forEach loop, but nothing changes and the buttons are still right to side of one another. What is going on with my loop?

```
const togglePen = document.createElement('button')
togglePen.innerText="Toggle pen"
togglePen.classList.add("common")

const toggleColor = document.createElement('button')
toggleColor.innerText = 'Toggle color'
toggleColor.classList.add("common")

const eraser = document.createElement('button')
eraser.innerText = 'Eraser'
eraser.classList.add("common")

const reset = document.createElement('button')
reset.innerText = 'Reset'
reset.classList.add("common")

//Styling the buttons, which doesn't work
buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".common")
buttons.forEach(button => {
    button.style.padding = '10px'
});

buttonMenu.append(togglePen, toggleColor, eraser, reset)
```

Comment: your `querySelectorAll` doesnt find your new buttons because you append them later

Comment: I think @Sysix might be right. But also your js doesn't seem to properly add the buttons to the html dom.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to copy your code in jsfiddle but it did not work.

I modified your code a bit so that the elements you have created actually get appended to the body.

I think the issue with your code is that the buttons are not being added to the html.

Without seeing your html it is difficult to answer.

```
const togglePen = document.createElement('button')
togglePen.innerText="Toggle pen"
togglePen.classList.add("common")

const toggleColor = document.createElement('button')
toggleColor.innerText = 'Toggle color'
toggleColor.classList.add("common")

const eraser = document.createElement('button')
eraser.innerText = 'Eraser'
eraser.classList.add("common")

const reset = document.createElement('button')
reset.innerText = 'Reset'
reset.classList.add("common")

//Styling the buttons, which doesn't work
buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".common")
buttons.forEach(button => {
    button.style.padding = '10px'
});
const body = document.querySelector('#test');

document.body.appendChild(reset);

buttonMenu.append(togglePen, toggleColor, eraser, reset)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jny3boqc/1/

Comment: If the buttons are not added to html, then I don't think I would even see them on screen. However, they are still rendered. Furthermore, when I add a new attribute via 'button.style.padding', the padding still gets rendered.

Comment: Here is my code if you want to see it in full
[link](https://jsfiddle.net/ViSpace/m7z130yv/2/)